# does meteor support DBRef yet?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, livequery

This question has been asked before but i have not seen any new(er) answers for over a year now.

I have been using php/mysql for some time now with extensive use of the mysql foreign key relationship, particularly where a child row has multiple parents (the child row ends up containing the primary key of two or more parent rows)

meteor looks exceptionally powerful and interesting.  i understand that mongoDB is the most well supported database and mongoDB uses DBRef to simulate the mysql foreign-key relationship.

does meteor now support the mongoDB DBRef structure?

i have yet to do anything with meteor except for watch some introductory videos.  before i start into it, i need to make sure meteor is going to be able to approximate what our current mysql foreign-key relationships are doing.

thank you very much.

UPDATE:  i cant help but wonder if meteor and [livequery](https://www.meteor.com/livequery) would work with mongoDB & DBRef?

Comment: I was asking the same thing myself. Looking forward to see any reponses :-)

Comment: While the question is a valid one, I don't believe it is fit for Stack Overflow. There are other places that you can and should bring this up or offer your opinion.

Comment: serkan - the question has been asked on StackOverflow several times but its been about two years since the question was raised.